# html input font

Tags: html

Css on the body tag:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    min-width: 1050px;
    min-height: 500px;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Works perfect, however it doesn't seem to work on input fields :S For some reason (while those input fields have NO styling) it uses Lucida Grande for input fields text and rest is just Helvetica, I am 100% sure there is no other font-family tag else where.

What is causing this and why?

Comment: can you please edit your question with the issue. just saying html input font is misleading and doesn't convey anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Input fields usually have their own style set in browser’s default style sheet. This typically means a browser-dependent font family and a font size of about 90%.

To set their font, you need to use a selector that refers to them, e.g. using

```
body, input { 
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;   /* if that’s what you want... */
  line-height: 1.4;  /* somewhat excessive */
  color: #333333;    /* if that’s what you want, but it reduces legibility */
  background: white; /* always set background when you set color */
}
body {
  min-width: 1050px; /* if you really want this... */
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

(but note that this also affects submit buttons).

Comment: if you want to avoid setting font family for input fields and are using a "reset" in your css just whack a `font-family: inherit;` and it will inherit the font specified for the body or other preceding parent element

Comment: @Yevgeniy, `inherit` is not supported by all browsers, and it would be quite unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following :

input {
    font-family: inherit;
}

Or set any other font, and let see does this change issue.

Comment: The main problem with `inherit` is that IE does not support it.